# mysql_query with $_SESSION or quotes

Tags: php

I'm having some grief with this and would appreciate some help. I have tried the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = $_SESSION['FirstName'] And tLastName = $_SESSION['LastName']");
```

but I get error "unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE".

I tried a number of ways with double and single quotes around the session variables but it always seems to find an error.

Eventually I gave up with that and set them before hand to $fn and $ln - then used that in the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = '$fn' And tLastName = '$ln'");
```

This worked fine ... until I came across a user with the last name O'Reilly and now the single quote in their name breaks it!

Help! Any idea how I get around this?

Comment: Consider PDO or MySQLi. `mysql_*` is going for a very long walk in the future, and wont be coming home.

Comment: Also holy hell read up on SQL injection and do not touch SQL until you do so. Also, use `{$_braces[]}` to escape in a string, but really, ***look up PHP Security***. I hope so badly that you don't store passwords, either...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys. The base of the code was done in Dreamweaver over a year ago. I needed something for a school and had no clue about MySQL/PHP. I've learned much more than I started with but still have a looong way to go. I 'll look to change to MySQLi soon. I also read up a little on injection and tried to hack mine using what I saw on the web, but I couldn't. I put this down to 2 things: the URL only ever shows the 'container' page and doesn't include ?id= etc. and all user login is authenticated with Active Directory. I'd still like to know how easy it is to hack tho!

Comment: if you're rewriting from scratch, use PDO. it'll make your life way, way easier :). MySQLi seems fine, but it's not as user-friendly and requires more work for the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **escape** your variables before using them in an SQL query!  If you don't, bad things can happen (SQL Injection!<sup>1</sup>).  Since you're using `mysql_`, you can do this.

```
$fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['FirstName']);
$ln = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['LastName']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = '$fn' And tLastName = '$ln'");
```

This is *exactly* the reason to *stop* using `mysql_` and switch to `PDO` (or `mysqli`)!  With those, you can use "prepared queries" and never have to worry about escaping again (it does it for you).  Please see this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Once you switch, you want either [`$mysqli->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`$dbh->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

<sub><sup>1</sup>See this for info on SQL Injection: http://bobby-tables.com/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

to escape the single quotes, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` before putting the variables into the query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fn)."' And tLastName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ln)."'");
```

The correct syntax for the first query (without the escaping now...):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = {$_SESSION['FirstName']} And tLastName = {$_SESSION['LastName']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on your inputs:

```
$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_SESSION['FirstName']);
$ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_SESSION['LastName']);
```

where `$link` is the link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()`. Then:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = '$fn' And tLastName = '$ln'");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'll repeat myself once again and say this - you shouldn't be using PHP `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqli or PDO.

Now, the problem with your query is that you're not making sure that the user won't be able to inject malicious code into your database. The query won't work with the last name "O'Reilly" because of the apostrophe `'`. It's breaking the MySQL query.
Before inserting data into the database please use a functions like `htmlspecialchars()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` (if you still insist on sticking with `mysql_*`)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `mysql_real_escape_string` or using `PDO`.

mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

PDO:

```
 // make a connection using mysql on PDO
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
 // make a query using params :fn and :ln
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT this FROM that WHERE tFirstName = :fn And tLastName = :ln");
 // bind value to these params
 // when binding params, PDO automaticaly escape it and quote it, it's the most safe way to avoid SQL Injection.
 $stmt->bindParam(':fn', $fn);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ln', $ln);
 // execute the created statement
 $stmt->execute();
 // fetch data from statement
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 // dump data
 sprintf("<pre>%s</pre>", printr($data,true));
```